# How do I collapse nested structures in Gson deserialization?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, deserialization

I'm building an API client for a service that uses a lot of deeply nested objects/arrays in the JSON response.  For example:

```
"foo":{
    "name":"something",
    "id":1
    "data":{
        "items":[
             ...
             //item objects
             ...
        ]        
    }
}
```

I'd like my parsed "foo" class to skip the "data" member and look something like this:

```
class Foo {
    int id;
    String name;
    List<Item> items;
}
```

What's the best way to use Gson to parse the JSON while eliminating the "data" layer in the response data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way, without writing a custom deserializer, would be just to add a wrapper object.

```
class Foo {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private Data data;

  static class Data {
    List<Item> items;
  }

  public int getId() { return id; }
  public String getName() { return name; }     
  public List<Item> getItems() { return data.items; }
}
```

With private fields and using getter methods, the wrapper `Data` object never gets exposed to the public API, so functionally it's the same.